# How to create a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

OK, this question seems to be silly but bear with me. When I trying to create a 2D array in C++, it gave me some warnings (`len` is an integer):

```cpp
double a[len][len];
// warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature
// warning: variable length array used
```

So I tried another:

```cpp
double **a = new double[len][len];
// error: only the first dimension of an allocated array may have dynamic size
// read of non-const variable 'len' is not allowed in a constant expression
```

How can I do it correctly in `C++11`?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(len, std::vector<int>(len));`

Comment: Array dimensions MUST be constant. Some compilers will allow the first bit of code to be more C-like. It's a fabulous way to blow the top off the stack, though. If you don't know the dimensions ahead of the time, I recommend using [something more like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301). You still get contiguous storage, but it's in Dynamic storage where usually you have much more memory.

Comment: There are many ways to do this with different trade-offs.

Comment: Also [this answer may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Answer (score -1):

```
double** a=new double*[len];
for(int i=0;i<len;++i)
{
   a[i]=new double[len];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a note on the destruction part to make it replace the automatic `double a[len][len];` variable would be good. With that, the use of a smart pointer - and ultimately `std::vector` to replace all the cumbersome memory management.

Comment: I recommend covering the destruction logic for completeness because clean up for this option is non-trivial.

Comment: This is the worst way to allocate a dynamic 2D array that have a uniform number of columns.  There are so many things wrong with it -- memory fragmentation, hard to diagnose an error if one of those `new[]` calls fail, etc.

Comment: @error [See this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Comment: I'd upvote if you add the freeing of memory.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez This is a terrible replacement for `double a[len][len];` but freeing the memory would make it somewhat complete at least.

Answer (score -2):

Are there any restrictions on what you can use? If you're planning to do array manipulations I'd say just use [Eigen] (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: This would make a good comment, but as an answer it's pretty weak.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to use `std::vector`.

Comment: And I think an additional 3rd party lib is unnecessary.

Comment: @ycao "_I don't want to use `std::vector`_" - why?

Comment: @ycao -- Why do you not want to use `std::vector`?  It is part of the C++ standard library since 1998.  What other C++ library functions are you also not willing to use?

Comment: I think it's still too complicated for a 2D array.

Comment: @ycao -- Why is it complicated?  Because you have to type in a few more letters when declaring one?

Comment: @ycao I'd say that the alternative you're faced with (implementing a safe version yourself) will be even more complicated.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think you're right...